# How to create a predefined polygon with specific size

Tags: google-maps

I have a initial Lat/Lng derive from click event in google maps.
Using that Lat/Lng, I want to be able to construct a rectangle polygon that is 2km by 2km. Since I already have a lat/lng, I attempted to find SE corners of a rectangle - using computeOffset.

```
  var initial_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  var south = spherical.computeOffset(initial_pos, 2000, 135); 
  var east  = spherical.computeOffset(initial_pos, 2000, 90);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    initial_pos,  south, east
  );
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map:map,
    bounds: bounds
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. To draw a rectangle you will need the bounds, which can be derived from two diagonally opposite vertices of the rectangle to be drawn. Let's say you have NW (NorthWest) corner and you are trying to draw a square of side s. You may then find out LatLng of the SE corner, using [computeOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeOffset), with distance as s*√2 (in meters) and heading as 135 (degrees).

Following are suggestions on the currently posted source code:

You should calculate a new position only once. Since this position is diagonally opposite, distance should be 2000*1.414. Also, note that the bounds is not initialized with LatLng. They are initialized with four variables. north and south are Lat values. east & west are Lng values. Here are my code change suggestions. Please try them. Please treat this as pseudo code and suite appropriate changes as needed.(Following code is now updated during my edit and should work. Ensure that libraries=geometry is added in the script tag, e.g.

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry&callback=initGMap">
    </script>)



  var initial_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(18.39,77.12);
  // initialize initial_pos variable based on click event or so
  var calculated_pos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initial_pos, 200*1.414, 135); 


  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({

    map: map,
    bounds:{ 
      north: initial_pos.lat(),
      south: calculated_pos.lat(),
      west: initial_pos.lng(),
      east: calculated_pos.lng()
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Ravindra, thanks for the help, I've updated my post based on your answer, can you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer and suggested some code changes.

Comment: Hey @Ravindra, so after I get north, south, west, east - to create a boundary, I did
var NW = new google.maps.LatLng(north, west)
var SE = new google.maps.LatLng(south, east)
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    NW, SE
  );
and passed the bounds to my rect. Does it look right?

Comment: Just to clarify, I had the other constructor of bounds in mind that took 4 values individually. On further lookup, I realized that the constructor of bounds accepts two LatLng as you are doing above.So this should work. In such a case we need not get north, south ... values. We could straight away use initial_pos and calculated_pos to construct the rectangle.

Comment: Could you also tell me why we multiplied by 2000*1.414

Comment: @babadahal 1.414 is actually square root of 2. As I wrote in my answer, since we want distance between diagonally opposite corners of a square, we will multiply the side of square by square root of 2.